# How can I use multiple gpus in cupy?

Tags: gpu, cupy

I am trying to parallelise multiple matrix multiplications using multiple GPUs in CUPY.

Cupy accelerates matrix multiplication (e.g. $A\times B$).
I am wondering if I have four square matrices A,B,C,D. I want to calculate AB and CD on two different local GPUs. How can I do it in CUPY?

For example, in tensorflow,

```py
for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
  with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
```

Is there a similar way in CUPY. The thing about Cupy is that it execute code straight away, so that it cannot run the next line (e.g. $C\times D$) until current line finishes (e.g. $A\times B$).

Thanks for Tos's help. Now the new questions is,
say I have ten of these matrices pairs stored in two 3d numpy array (say ?*?*10). How can I write a loop to store the result of multiplication?

```
anumpy #size(1e5,1e5,10)
bnumpy #size(1e5,1e5,10)

for i in range(10):
   #say I have 3 gpus
   with cupy.cuda.Device(i % 3):
      a = cupy.array(anumpy[:,:,i])
      b = cupy.array(bnumpy[:,:,i])
      ab[:,:,math.floor(i/3)] = a @ b
```

How can I combine these 3 ab in different devices?
Can I have arrays with the same name in different GPUs?

Answer (score 2):

Use `with cupy.cuda.Device(i)` and avoid blocking operations.  For example, to compute matmul of pairs of CPU arrays, send the results to CPU (`cupy.asnumpy`) after all matmul operations are called.

```
a = cupy.array(a)
b = cupy.array(b)
ab = a @ b
# ab = cupy.asnumpy(ab)  # not here
with cupy.cuda.Device(1):
    c = cupy.array(c)
    d = cupy.array(d)
    cd = c @ d
    cd = cupy.asnumpy(cd)
ab = cupy.asnumpy(ab)
```

Comment: Hi Tos,
Your answer helps. One more question, how can I form these in a loop? See my edit to original question for details.

Comment: This answer is really helpful. I think the blocking operations means data exchange between CPU and GPU, more specifically speaking.

Answer (score 1):

CuPy does not synchronize the device execution in most operations. The code like `A.dot(B)` returns immediately after launching the matrix product on the device, without waiting for the device side operation itself, so if the operation is heavy enough (e.g. the matrices are large), the computation effectively overlaps with the second matrix product on another device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand the question properly, but I guess it can be something like this:

```py
def my_cal(gpu_id, anumpy, bnumpy):
  a = None
  b = None
  ab = None

  with cupy.cuda.Device(gpu_id):
    for i in range(10):
        a = cupy.array(anumpy[:,:,i])
        b = cupy.array(bnumpy[:,:,i])
        ab[:,:,math.floor(i/3)] = a @ b
  return cupy.asnumpy(ab)


np_ab0 = my_cal(0, anumpy, bnumpy)
np_ab1 = my_cal(1, anumpy, bnumpy)
np_ab2 = my_cal(2, anumpy, bnumpy)
```

Comment: if ab is stored in the first cpu, you cannot access it from the second and the third gpu.